# How to sort two vectors to ensure the data still relates

Tags: c++, vector

I have the vectors:

```
vector<string> countriesName;
vector<long> countriesPop;
```

These contain data such as

```
countriesName = {"UK","GER","IRE"};
countriesPop = {561655,6518,5168};
```

I am trying to work out how to sort the countries population from smallest to largest while keeping the index's between the two vectors the same.

I have seen other solutions which require to use a struct and a vector of the structs. However as I have other functions which already rely on the original vectors I would preferably find a solution using these so I dont have to rework a lot of other functions.

Therefore the output after sorting should go from

```
UK 561655
GER 6518
IRE 5168
```

To

```
IRE 5168
GER 6518
UK 561655
```

Comment: You probably misunderstood the other solutions -- all that needs to be done is to create a separate vector of indexes, then sort that, and use the result to resort the original vectors. No need to change the structure of the existing vectors.

Comment: Hmmm.  A vector of `struct`s would make more sense though, `countriesName` and `countriesPop` clearly belong together, and if you carry on as you are, things are likely to get messy (again) somewhere down the line.  If it was me, I _would_ put them both into a struct (along with any other information pertaining to a country - more might come along later, don't you think?).

Comment: OK, that might have some knock-on effects, but if you bite the bullet now, your future self will thank you for it.  One thing that might ease the pain is to add a couple of [conversion operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) to that struct.  Your existing code would probably then need fewer changes, although it's not really a good long-term solution because you would be, IMO, abusing those operators somewhat.  And you can then sort that struct by passing a suitable comparison function to `std::sort` (people often use a lambda).